# select an random page with django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to select a random page with Django but I don't know how to call the function.

I tried to call it with an URL but it didn't work.

**views.py:**

```
def random_page(request):
    entries = util.list_entries() # list of wikis
    selected_page = random.choice(entries)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/layout.html", {
        "random_page": selected_page
    })
```

**urls.py:**

```
from . import views
app_name = "encyclopedia"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:page_title>", views.wiki_page, name="wiki_page"),
    path("create", views.add_entry, name="add_entry"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("wiki/edit/<str:page_title>", views.edit_page, name="edit_page")
]
```

**layout.html:**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <h2>Wiki</h2>
        <form action="{% url 'encyclopedia:search' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
        </form>
            <a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:index' %}">Home</a>
            <a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:add_entry' %}">Create New Page</a> 
            <a href=wiki/{{ random_page }}>Random Page</a>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not redirect to a given page. You thus redirect the browser to a page with a given page title. The advantage is that you make it simpler and only have to write the redirect logic once.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def random_page(request):
    entries = util.list_entries() # list of wikis
    selected_page = random.choice(entries)
    return redirect('encyclopedia:wiki_page', page_title=selected_page)
```

You then specify a path in your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("random/", views.random_page, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:page_title>", views.wiki_page, name="wiki_page"),
    path("create", views.add_entry, name="add_entry"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("wiki/edit/<str:page_title>", views.edit_page, name="edit_page")
]
```

If you then visit `/random` it will redirect to a random page.

Comment: @marcelofreitas: you define an extra path, and link to that?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the view in this way

```
def random_page(request):
    entries = util.list_entries()
    selected_page = random.choice(entries)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('wiki', args=[selected_page]))
```