# Django - creating a random page selector

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, cs50

I'm hoping to create a link on a homepage that, when clicked, will randomly redirect the user to 1 out of 5 entry pages (CSS, Django, Git, HTML, Python) on the site.

I saw someone else asking essentially the same question ([select an random page with django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797803/select-an-random-page-with-django)) and I tried to follow the 2 answers but now when I click on my Random Page link I have an error:

> NoReverseMatch at /wiki/random/
> Reverse for 'index' with arguments '('Git',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/random/$', 'wiki/$']
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/random/
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch

**views.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from . import util
import random

def random_page (request):
    entries = util.list_entries()
    selected_page = random.choice(entries)
    return HttpResponseRedirect (reverse('index', args=[selected_page]))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("css/", views.css, name="CSS"),
    path("django/", views.django, name="Django"),
    path("git/", views.git, name="Git"),
    path("html/", views.html, name="HTML"),
    path("python/", views.python, name="Python"),
    path("createnew/", views.createnew, name="New_Entry"),
    path("random/", views.random_page, name="index")
]
```

**layout.html**

```
<div>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Random Page</a>
</div>
```

I was a little worried about making the homepage and random_page have the same name "index" but even when I changed the name in views.py to "random" and then changed it in layouts.html it still didn't work.

Comment: Glancing at those answers to the linked question, it looks like you've chosen the wrong one - I don't understand how that is intended to work. The other answer is much better, although the URLs are structured somewhat differently from yours. It's not clear what your `list_entries` returns, but it seems to me that here it should just contain a list of the URL names, and then you can `return HttpResponseRedirect (reverse(selected_page))`

Comment: Also, you may want to just have `path("<str:name>", views.page, name="Page")` that covers all the pages instead of one for each page. Otherwise it'll be challenging to add a new page.